# How to find the maximum resolution link of new Instagram posts?

Tags: facebook, browser, instagram, instagram-api

I’ve discovered with instaloader (a tool downloadable from github) that Instagram now saves posts with a size larger than 1080 pixels height or width, I think 1440 maximum. But adding “/media/?size=l” to a link post I’m only able to get the image with 1080 pixels (height or width) maximum.
I certainly know there is a greater quality version of a post that the one “/media/?size=l” gives me because when I compare this version with the one downloaded with instaloader the difference is notable, but I have not been able to find the link of it.
Does anyone know how to find it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media

> **Photo Requirements**
>
> - Maximum file size: 8MiB
> - Aspect ratio: Must be within a 4:5 to 1.91:1 range
> - Minimum width: 320 (will be scaled up to the minimum if necessary)
> - Maximum width: 1440 (will be scaled down to the maximum if necessary)
> - Height: Varies, depending on width and aspect ratio
> - Formats: JPEG